# I have used double quotes in the variable and echo is not give me any output

Tags: bash

I have made a bash script in which I am checking the status of a service running on a server. If the output is "Running", then it should print "Service is running" else "Not running". But I didn't see the output of `echo` when my first condition is true.

```
STATUS=`/etc/init.d/webservice-interface status`

if [ "$STATUS" == "Running" ]
then echo Webservice is Running
else echo not running
fi
```

Comment: Now I am getting below error.

Comment: [root@wsisbibappuat02 opt]# sh new.sh
new.sh: line 6: $'[\E[0;32mRunning': command not found
not running

Comment: I don't know what you did to get that error message, but if it derives from `$STATUS`, that suggests it contains more than just "Running" -- like, at least one square bracket and a color change escape code. Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script to get an execution trace, and see *exactly* what `STATUS` is being set to.

Answer (score -2):

You should add the message of echo into double quote or single quote.
It should like that:

```
if [[ "$STATUS" =~ "Running" ]]; then  
echo "Webservice is Running"  
else echo "not running"  
fi
```

Comment: getting below output.[root@wsisbibappuat02 opt]# sh -x new.sh
++ /etc/init.d/webservice-interface status
+ STATUS='Running [46582]'
+ '[' 'Running [46582]' == Running ']'
+ echo Service is not running
Service is not running

Comment: What is the return message of "/etc/init.d/webservice-interface status" command? Based on your provided code, the return message must be matched with "Running". So provide me the return message of this cmd, I will edit my answer to give you my suggestion

Comment: [root@wsisbibappuat02 opt]# sh -x new.sh
++ /etc/init.d/webservice-interface status
+ STATUS='Running [996]'
+ '[' 'Running [996]' == Running ']'
+ echo Service is not running
Service is not running

Comment: As you can see in the result. The return message is mismatch with your expected output. So my suggestion is that you should edit the if condition to "if [[ "$STATUS" =~ Running ]]; then"